# Operating system?

Tags: pi-2

I just got my Raspberry Pi 2. I'm using my tv as a monitor and a keyboard. The first thing that popped up on the screen was download options. I clicked all of them because I had enough space and then pressed continue.

When it was about 7% complete, it said "error" and to close the screen. I did and the pi turned off... Now, it says "select operating system", but none are listed.

Comment: It sounds like you are using a NOOBS based card.   You might as well re-flash the card and start again, but first make sure you are using a sufficient power supply (1+ amp output).

Comment: Most of the OS's in the NOOBS menu are incompatible with the Pi 2 (Pidora, Arch, *_Pi1...)

Answer (score 2):

Install raspbian or OSMC from here;

https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

I have nothing nice to say about NOOBS which you are having trouble with.